# PHP Loop based on row number for bootstrap columns

Tags: php, row, col

I have one design issue that I want to solve. I've spend 2 days on this and I know that its an easy one...

I want to echo the articles with this order: col-8, col-4, col-4, col-8, col-8,col-4... and so on.

[image]

I've made it to echo the articles like this: col-8, col-4, col-8, col-4, col-8, col-4... and so on.

```php
if ($article->id % 2 == 0) { echo 4; } elseif ($article->id % 2 == 1) { echo 8; }
```

I know that I have to use the loop inside one other loop, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your modulus conditional to fit the loop / starting point you want.

Give this a go:

```
if ($article->id % 4 == 0 || $article->id % 4 == 1) { echo 8; } else { echo 4; }
```

https://ideone.com/IneWWC

Comment: Now it prints the articles like this: col-8, col-, col-, col-4... because of the quotient of divisions.

Comment: Are your article ids not sequential?

Comment: They are...(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc). But When you divide the id 2 or 3 with 4, you get 0.5 for 2 and 0.75 for 3. So they !== 0. I know that I have to use on more loop to invert every row which % 2 == 0.

Comment: Of course, so then only the 1st and 4th iteration will return a number that matches either 1 or 0, giving you your two on, two off sequence starting with one on. Have a look at the ideone link I posted in the answer, should give a better explanation.

Comment: shouldn't that `|` be `||`? what's there now is bitwise.

Comment: It should indeed ;)